# Jenkins Pipeline: readFile method is adding a '?' at the start of file contents

Tags: .net, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is a strange behavior I'm facing with Jenkins Pipeline method readFile. Here is how I'm calling it:

```
def file=readFile file: "D:\\AssemblyInfo.cs", encoding: "UTF-8"
echo file
```

And here is the output. Observe the '?' at the start.

```
?using System.Reflection;
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("9.8.16")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("9.8.16")]
```

This is happening even if I don't mention `encoding: "UTF-8"`. This question mark is not there in the original file and will fail the dot net project compilation.

Any idea why this is happening and how to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you **sure** there is nothing extra before the first character of the file? Such as the UTF-8 BOM? How did you verify that there is nothing there in the original file?

Comment: See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53901

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen because I'm running the same piece of code on my local Jenkins server and this is not happening...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the writing without the encoding. That operation had corrupted the original `.cs` file. And since then all the readings included the question mark.
Once I put back the original file and added the `encoding: "UTF-8"` to **both read and write**, everything works fine.